# Convert java string to geojson using java

Tags: java, json, leaflet, geojson

I want to convert my string json to geojson for leaflet and this is my json

```
[
  {
    "longitude": "xxx",
    "latitude": "xxx",
    "kode_toko": "xxx",
    "nama_toko": "xxx",
    "postal_code": xxx
  },
```

etc (there is more like this in my json)..

This is my code for convert data from my database to json string

```
List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
Items item = null;

while(rs.next()) {
  item = new Items("","","","",0);
  //json = rs.getString("t");
  item.latitude = rs.getString("latitude");
  item.longitude = rs.getString("longitude");
  item.code = rs.getString("code");
  item.name = rs.getString("name");
  item.postalcode = rs.getInt("postal_code");
  data.add(item);

  //System.out.println("Items: " +data);
  //System.out.println("Item " +item);
}       

//convert to json
GsonBuilder build = new GsonBuilder();
build.setPrettyPrinting();
Gson gson = build.create(); 
String json = gson.toJson(data); //convert ke string`
```

How to convert this json string data to geojson data?
Thanks before

Answer (score 2):

GeoJSON is JSON, so instead of building the JSON you post from you data, just build the final GeoJSON,

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [xxx, yyy]
  },
  "properties": {
    "kode_toko": "www",
    "nama_toko": "uuu",
    "postal_code": "vvv"
  }
}
```

BTW, in `coordinates` xxx is longitude and yyy is latitude.

[GeoJSON](https://geojson.org)

Comment: yeah i know but is that build manually or ...?
because i got the data from database and the data is so many.. about 18 thousand data's

Comment: and how to build the final GeoJson directly instead put the value in List and change it to json